# Definition of first order infinitesimal number using equivalence classes

Tags: limits, functions, equivalence-relations, infinitesimals, synthetic-differential-geometry

I read about model construction in infinitesimal differential geometry (http://www.iam.fmph.uniba.sk/amuc/_vol-73/_no_2/_giordano/giordano.pdf , page 3-6)

I can't understand how equivalence class generated by $h(t)=t$ could be a first order infinitesimal number. How is it possible? What is main idea of this? How does it work?

> $(1.1)$ $\forall h \in D: f(h) = f(0) + h \cdot f'(0)$
>
> $(1.2)$   $\exists! m \in R: \forall h \in D: f(h) = f(0) + h \cdot m$
>
> If we try to construct a model for $(1.2)$ a natural idea is to think
> our new numbers as equivalence classes $[h]$ of usual functions $h: R
> \to R$. In such a way we can hope both to include the real field using
> classes generated by constant functions, and that the class generated
> by $h(t)=t$ could be a first order infinitesimal number. To understand
> how to define this equivalence relation we can see $(1.1)$ in the
> following sense:
>
> $(1.3)$    $$f(h(t)) \sim f(0) + h(t) \cdot f'(0)$$
>
> If we think $h(t)$ "sufficiently similar to $t$", we can define $\sim$
> so that $(1.3)$ is equivalent to:
>
> $$\lim \limits_{t\to 0} \frac{f(h(t)) - f(0) - h(t) \cdot f'(0)}{t}=0$$
>
> that is:
>
> $(1.4)$        $$x \sim y   :\iff \lim \limits_{t\to 0} \frac{x(t)-y(t)}{t}
> = 0$$

Thanks.